# Yii Database Migration

Tags: yii, migration

Hello guys I am new to yii frame work and I am following larry ullman's instructions 
on the e-book.
The problem I have is: when I'm creating new migration I keep on getting this error

```
The migration directory does not exists:application.migrations

I use the command : $ yiic migrate create <name>
```

Thank you guys for helping me understand yii.

Comment: do you have directory "project/protected/migrations"? is it writeable?

Comment: I do have the directory "protected/migrations" but I dont know If its writeable? how will I check that?

Comment: In unix/linux you can check `ls -la projectpath/protected/migrations` What webserver do you use?

Comment: I am currently using XAMPP Sir

Comment: didnt worked my OS is windows

Comment: where `yiic` executed from? it should be from `protected` directory of your project. I mean you should execute `cd /project/protected/` before migrate

Comment: also, there must be `yiic.bat` in `protected`

Comment: yes there is Sir? how will I change file permissions?

Comment: Yes I did execute it in /proj/protected/

Comment: Thanks Sir Russlan I have managed to fix the problem lol I was using the framework yiic i dont know why cd /proj/protected did not worked..What I did is just simply added the drive D:\xampp\htdocs\proj\protected\yiic migrate create <name> lol..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have noticed that the answer for this issue have been answered in the comments section, but may not be noticable for others.

Just to summarize:

1. You need to execute the `yiic` inside the `protected` directory
2. There should be an `yiic.bat` inside the `protected` directory
3. In some cases, the `migration` directory inside the `protected` directory must be available beforehand and is writable.

Comment: I didn't have the yiic.bat (as well as the yiic file) in my protected directory, your answer helped me...thanks.